# Hooking up a 4-20mA current output directly to a scope or a DAQ?

Tags: 4-20ma

I have a sensor which outputs both voltage and current optional. But the current output is recommended for less than 500 Ohm in data sheet.

I'm afraid if someone just hooka up this current output without a shunt-resistor directly to a  scope or a DAQ which has 1Mega-ohm or 1Giga-ohm input impedance. Would the sensor get damaged? Is it risky?

Comment: All ways use a burden resistor. The open circuit voltage may damage the sensor (it might be internally protected) and 4-20mA sensors are designed to use a resistor to develop a voltage across. The value should be in the instructions/manual.

Comment: 500 Ohm maximum load resistance probably means that the compliance voltage of this thing is only a bit more than 10 V. Thus, if you use a resistor of more than 500 Ohm, it will not be able to produce a current of 20 mA. For a really big resistor, it won't even be able to get to 4 mA -- for example, your 1 MOhm resistor will allow a maximum current of 10 µA, which is far outside the specification. Whether it will be damaged by violating the manufacturer's requirements is something that nobody here will be able to tell you, at least not without some detail about what the sensor actually is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unlikely to be damaging to the sensor, it will simply not be able to raise the voltage high enough to produce the correct current value.

The device is specified at 500 ohm maximum so it can only produce at maximum a 10V output, 20mA * 500ohm.
At a maximum of 10V this would only give you 10V/1Mohm = 10uA.

The only way your scope or DAQ could be damaged is if their inputs are rated for a maximum input of less than 10V